# A question on on inverse image of mapping

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given $F:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R }$ to be continuous function.

Suppose $F(I)$ and $F(I')$ are non-overlapping closed intervals (for some  closed intervals $I, I' \subseteq [a,b]$).

By intervals are non-overlapping, we mean by intervals are disjoint except possible at endpoints.

By some investigation, $I$ and $I'$  may overlap in some case.
Aside from taking $F$ to be **monotonic**, is there any possible condition forcing this intervals to be non-overlapping?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If a point $a$ lies in both $I$ and $I'$ then $f(a)$ is in both $f(I)$ and $f(I').$ This contradicts your assumption that $f(I)$ and $f(I')$ are non-ovrlapping. So $I$ and $I'$ are disjoint after all.

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you for the response. For the case, $a$ lies on common endpoint of $I$ and $I'$
and that max $F(I)$ is attained at point $a$  and \min $F(I') $ is attained at point a.

Then, $F(I)$ and $F(I')$ are non-overlapping (as they only intersect at the endpoint).
\\
Also, ive notice that
given the hypothesis $F(I)$ and $F(I')$ are non-overlapping.
$I$ and $I'$ may overlap as long as $F$ is monotonic on parts where they overlap.

Comment: I believe you are using "nonoverlapping" to mean "disjoint except possibly at a common eendpoint" for two intervals. [I was interpreting nonoverlapping as disjoint.] I do not follow your meaning in the sentence of your comment beginning "Also". Because that sentence seems to imply that closed intervals which intersect in a common closed interval of positive length are to also be called "nonoverlapping".

Comment: For this discussion you need a precise definition as to what "nonoverlapping" is to mean for two intervals. [And in my opinion it would be better not to use such misleading terminology, and simply spell out what you intend.

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you. I already added the definition. Which is precisely what you have mentioned.

Comment: Your added definition excludes an overlap in a positive length subinterval, against your comment beginning "Also" in one of your previous comments.

Comment: @coffeemath thank you again, in my end there is a misleading example I overlook. your first comment helped me a lot. 

 my comment after "also",

There are case where $I$ and $I′$ may overlap say $I' \cap I = [u,v]$ with $u<v$.
It is due to that I'm thinking that the hypothesis can still true for some function with $F:[u,v]\to \mathbb{R}$ monotonic on $[u,v]$ , but all due to my mistake.  
My apologies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144539/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-raijin).